# Meteor on Ubuntu WSL: PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU

Tags: android-studio, meteor

On my Ubuntu/WSL installation I'm getting the following error when running `meteor run android-device`:

```
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

How do I resolve this missing emulator issue?

I have checked my paths and these seem to be ok:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=/home/user/.meteor:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/etc/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/etc/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export ANDROID_BIN=/opt/android-studio-2021.2.1/android-studio/bin
```

I can also check that I have an emulator installed:

```
user@ASUS-i7:/etc/Android/Sdk/tools$ ./emulator -list-avds
Pixel_5_API_30
user@ASUS-i7:/etc/Android/Sdk/tools$
```

Android Studio Version:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-wsl2
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Current Desktop: Undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the windows `adb` command and creating a symlink within Ubuntu solved it.

```
sudo mv /etc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /etc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb_bk


sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Users/44739/Downloads/platform-tools_r33.0.2-windows-adb/platform-tools/adb.exe /etc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
```